# Converting values in Parameters or a HashWithIndifferentAccess to a useable hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, parameters, haml, rails-activerecord

I'm having trouble finding a way to convert from a parameter hash or a hash with indifferent access to a hash when the values contain hashes.

**I'm having trouble converting from this:**

```
hash_indif = {"1570"=>"{:enabled=>false}",
              "1571"=>"{:enabled=>false}",
              "1572"=>"{:enabled=>false}",
              "1573"=>"{:enabled=>false}",
              "1574"=>"{:enabled=>false}",
              "1575"=>"{:enabled=>false}",
              "1576"=>"{:enabled=>false}",
              "1577"=>"{:enabled=>false}",
              "1578"=>"{:enabled=>false}"}
```

**To this:**

```
hash_thing = {1570 => {:enabled => false},
              1571 => {:enabled => false},
              1572 => {:enabled => false},
              1573 => {:enabled => false},
              1574 => {:enabled => false},
              1575 => {:enabled => false},
              1576 => {:enabled => false},
              1577 => {:enabled => false},
              1578 => {:enabled => false}}
```

I'd like to be able to do with method chaining if at all possible.

**Additional Information**

This situation resulted from trying to update multiple attributes off the same key.

**Haml:**

```
- @a_feature.each do |af|
  .form-inline.radio-group
    %label= af.feature.name
    =radio_button "a_feature", af.id, [enabled: true], {checked: af.enabled, class:'form-control'}
    %label Yes
    =radio_button "a_feature", af.id, [enabled: false], {checked: !af.enabled, class:'form-control'}
    %label No
```

**Parameters:**

```
 {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"patch",
 "a_feature"=>{
 "296"=>"{:enabled=>true}",
 "344"=>"{:enabled=>false}",
 "376"=>"{:enabled=>false}",
 "commit"=>"Save",
 "agency_id"=>"7"}
```

Comment: Are you looking for something that works on all hashes with `a_hash.to_s` values, or something that works in this very specific case, where the value is in a symbol / hashrocket / boolean format?  Also, how is this getting created?  Is `#to_s` getting called on the `{:enabled=>false}` hashes somewhere?  I haven't really seen a `HashWithIndifferentAccess` where the functionality of the hash is compromised like this (not that that means anything, it's just confusing).

Comment: you could certainly do this with `eval`, eg `res = {}; h.keys.each { |k| res[eval(k)] = eval(h[k]) }` - but I'd strongly question the sanity of any such solution and would look at how we got into this situation in the first place if possible. Not sure how method chaining would apply or help.

Comment: @sbeam That worked (post it as a solution if you wish). I'll come back and post details on how I got to the situation in a few. Thanks!

Comment: @Blinky That works, but using `eval()` is almost always a bad idea. Some bad guy need only figure out how to get some nasty code into one of those strings, and your system is pwned

Comment: @Gene Ohh, thanks for the warning. Will need to find another work around or fix the situation in general.

Comment: @sbeam I edited the post to add additional details on how the situation occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick workaround without using eval

```
def to_bool(str)
    str == 'true'
end

new_hash = Hash.new
hash_indif.each do |i, j|
    inner_hash = Hash.new
    match_data = /^{:(enabled)=>(false|true)}$/.match(j)
    inner_hash[match_data[1].intern] = to_bool match_data[2]
    new_hash[i.to_i] = inner_hash
end
```

The new_hash variable contains the output you need -

```
{1570=>{:enabled=>false}, 1571=>{:enabled=>false}, 1572=>{:enabled=>false}, 1573=>{:enabled=>false}, 1574=>{:enabled=>false}, 1575=>{:enabled=>false}, 1576=>{:enabled=>false}, 1577=>{:enabled=>false}, 1578=>{:enabled=>false}}
```